# error loading and using RSQLite in Windows

Tags: r, rsqlite

RSQLite installed normally.
First I try to connect to a database and get an error.

```
library(DBI)
mydb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "")
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  erro na avaliação do argumento 'drv' na seleção do método para a função 'dbConnect': '.onLoad falhou em loadNamespace() para 'RSQLite', detalhes:
  chamada: NULL
  erro: 'hash' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rlang''
```

After a little research here, I updated `rlang` and `DBI`.
Then I tried to load `RSQLite` and get error too.

```
library(RSQLite)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RSQLite’:
 .onLoad falhou em loadNamespace() para 'RSQLite', detalhes:
  chamada: NULL
  erro: 'hash' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rlang'
```

It seems that `RSQLite` is trying to use a function (`hash`) that do not exists on `rlang`.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was just updating `rlang`.
I thought I already had updated it, but @krlmlr kindly suggested to update.